# Multiple Openlayers 3 popup styles?

Tags: javascript, css, popup, openlayers-3

I am wondering if there is a way to style separate ol3 popups?

At the moment I have a popup overlay that displays basic information, but I need to completely change the way in which it displays when querying a particular layer.

The popups are only javascript variables (var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();) So I don't know how I can individually change the css properties for each variable?

Is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: You need array I think. Is this what you mean: `var overlaysArray = [new ol.Overlay(), new ol.Overlay(), new ol.Overlay()];` (grabbed from GIS.stackexchange)

Comment: How am I think able to explicitly define css styles for each of those overlays?